# Position UIBarButtonItem on edge of UINavigationBar

Tags: uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Is it possible to position a custom image UIBarButton item on the left or right **edge** of a UINavigationBar? The way I've created my buttons it looks best if the edge of the button is touching the edge of the UINavigationBar.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Are you creating your view with Interface Builder, or programmatically?

Comment: Using Storyboards actually. I'd rather create everything through storyboards. Basically, I'd just like to easily remove the padding on the right side of a right UIBarButton and the padding on the left of a left UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is subclassing UINavigation bar and overriding layout subviews.

In my example I move my button to the far left edge if it has a tag of 900.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    //override the navigation bar to move classes with 900 to the ledge
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {  
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {  
            if (view.tag == 900)
                view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 88, 44);
        }

    }
}
```